# Get absolute path of current source file in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Is it possible to get the absolute path of the current source file in Haskell?

I could only find one relevant function: [`getCurrentDirectory`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/directory-1.0.0.3/docs/System-Directory.html#v%3AgetCurrentDirectory) from `System.Directory`, but it "returns an absolute path to the current directory of the calling process.", not the path of the current file.

(I need it to read sample inputs which are located in the same folder as the source file; If there's any better way to do it, that will be helpful too!)

Comment: What do you mean by "current file"? The path to the compiled executable that is being run? Or the source file of the module? Or something else?

Comment: @shang, sorry, I meant source file.

Answer (score 6):

You can use CPP. If you compile this file

```
{-# LANGUAGE CPP #-}
main = print __FILE__
```

it will print the path to the source as you passed it to `ghc` – which may or may not be the full path, though:

```
/tmp $ ghc --make mypath.hs 
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( mypath.hs, mypath.o )
Linking mypath ...
/tmp $ ./mypath 
"mypath.hs"
/tmp $ ghc --make /tmp/mypath.hs 
Linking /tmp/mypath ...
/tmp $ ./mypath 
"/tmp/mypath.hs"
```

Answer (score 5):

As an alternative, the [file-embed](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/file-embed) package can be used here. It uses template haskell to embed files/directories.

This can be very useful to embed resources or configs in the executable. It may not be advisable to read the sample input this way though. `data-files` in cabal might be better alternative as already pointed out earlier in this thread.

Comment: You can run into the same issue with file-embed, but there is a handy function now in 0.0.10 : http://hackage.haskell.org/package/file-embed-0.0.10/docs/src/Data-FileEmbed.html#makeRelativeToProject

Answer (score 1):

The [PseudoMacros package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pseudomacros-0.0.1/docs/PseudoMacros.html) might be useful. According to the description, it provides C-like strings for the current file name etc.

UPDATE

The file name returned by PseudoMacros equals the path passed to ghc (same behaviour as @JoachimBreitner mentioned in his answer), so

```
 import PseudoMacros

 main :: IO ()
 main = putStrLn ("Hello from " ++ $__FILE__ ++ ", line " ++ show $__LINE__ ++ "!")
```

will print

```
Hello from tmp.hs, line 5!
```

or

```
Hello from /tmp/tmp.hs, line 5!
```

depending on whether you provided a relative or absolute filename to ghc.

Comment: It doesn’t seem to include the directory, though.

Comment: @JoachimBreitner The behaviour is the same as for your solution - see my updated answer

Comment: Ok, sorry for doubting without checking myself.

Comment: No problem - in fact, your comment triggered me to investigate further, so thanks for doubting me :-)